# Using step 1 of the FTOC to solve the derivative of the integral.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I was going to say that the derivative would simply be the equation inside the integral, since if you're taking the derivative of the integral, but that's not right. Does anyone know how to go about doing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Key Idea**

In general,
$$ \int_a^b f(t) dt = -\int_b^a f(t)dt.$$